# Strengthening surface mount connections for parts

Tags: pcb-design, connector, surface-mount

With normal use, some of my surface-mount parts are detaching from the PCB (they pull the pads off the board and sometimes rip up the traces as well). I have had this happen with audio jacks and battery holders.

What's the best way to strengthen their pads? In my case is not an option to use through-hole parts and I cannot add other mechanical connections.

I've read about adding vias to the pad, but I have also read they may prevent the part from soldering properly during the machine process. Maybe making the pad larger but covering the extra area with solder mask?

Comment: The copper is detaching from the board. Sorry this wasn't clear. I just edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Some alternative parts use smd with trough hole like retention, which you or the assembler just solder.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the pads larger which will help prevent peeling. But the pad dimension will need to be wider in the direction that is perpendicular in the direction you you expect it to peel in. This will make the more difficult to solder.

You can also use RTV silicone if the part is big enough. You want neutral cure silicone. Not the regular hardware stuff that produces acetic acid (vinegar) which you can smell on curing.

Or stick the board in an enclosure with the appropriate cutouts so the handling forces are applied to the enclosure rather than the pads.

Comment: Would the larger pads would be difficult to solder because they dissipate the heat too much, or for another reason? If the pad is larger but covered with solder mask, at least I don't believe it would affect placement. Do you know if assembly houses can use RTV silicon as part of the machine assembly process, or is that done by hand? In my case I need the board itself to support the components, so I am looking to see if it is possible to address in the PCB design. The parts fall off rather rarely, so a modest improvement would help. Does not need to be perfect in this application.

Comment: @Tristan They are more difficult to heat. Not really an issue in an oven. However, tombstoning is an issue for ovens but these sound like large components. Is this for production? You'd have to ask your board house, but I believe machines do exist.

Comment: @Tristan Ask your assembler I mean. Not your board house.